# How to recreate a db for each test run?

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I need to recreate a database for each test run. I'm using `Robotium` to automate tests for my application, so each test extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. What I've found out is that I can use `RenamingDelegatingContext` in order to mock a new `Context`. But as long as I'm extending from `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` I can't use `setActivityContext()` which is in `ActivityUnitTestCase` class. Might be I just went the wrong way. Please advice another possible way to recreate a db, if any. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried for a while to use the renamingdelegatingcontext but failed because as far as I could tell to use it within an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 I would have to mock out the application which I couldn't do because our application actually extended application and had specific code in the onCreate and it became a whole horrible problem.

I then took the easy route and just clearedthe database between every run (as well as shared preferences and cookies)

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME)
```

I found this to (surpisingly) not be too slow (not in comparison to testing anything through the GUI anyway.) You might find that you need to call your applications onCreate manually each test though depending on how your application is coded in order to make it setup correctly but this is fairly easy to do.

Oh and just to say i used to put all this code in a new testclass that extended ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 so it happened automally in the setup/tear downs.